# getting error IndexError: ('list index out of range', u'occurred at index 193')

Tags: python, pandas

```
latlon1_df = pd.read_csv("latlon1.csv")

from uszipcode import Zipcode
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)

def dany(x):
    result = search.by_coordinates(x[0],x[1])
    return result[0].zipcode

df["zipcode"] = df.apply(dany, axis=1)
```

Comment: I am using two columns, it is executed till 192nd row

Comment: did you check the quality of your data around line 192, i.e the csv file?

Comment: yes, it's all latitude and longitude. it contains 64k rows

Comment: it may be due to empty result from API( search engine) for lat-long.